# 1024x768 wide screen in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: display-resolution, 17.04

I have an Acer Switch alpha 12 running Ubuntu 17.04 and for the most part everything works perfectly. But when I connect to my TV the aspect ratio for the native resolution (1024x768) is only available in the 4:3 aspect ratio.

Googling around I've found that this is the expected aspect ratio for that resolution, however my crappy 720p Samsung Plasma manages a 16:9 aspect ratio by changing the shape of the pixels. From what I've found it's referred to as "wide screen 720p" or something like that. I imagine it requires so manual editing of config file, but I can't find any information out there about fixing this.

There is a sort-of work around I found here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/guerrilla-tactics-force-screen-mode-ubuntu

I set my resolution to the closest 16:9 resolution which is 1368x768.

but this isn't a native resolution so everything is a little off visually.
Anybody out there have any experience?

EDIT:

I guess I was wrong about windows displaying the correct aspect ratio. I thought it did, but when I looked again I was wrong. Windows has the same stretched-looking 720 aspect ratio...My question has been answered already in a couple of older posts here already and I guess this is the best I can do for windows or linux....Time to get a new TV?

Comment: As you recognized yourself there is no such thing as 1024*768 in 16:9 (No need to google just make the division 1024/768 = 4/3.) So choosing the closest 16:9 is the correct solution.

Comment: Look at `man xrandr` if you want to experiment with non-standard resolutions.

Comment: I used xrandr to manual set that resolution. The issue I have is that most, if not all, other devices find a way to handle 720 widescreen. Windows for example with the same setup manages to get 16:9 aspect ratio. My PS4 manages this too. I was hoping there was a way to figure it out on linux. I'm close with the manual resolution change, but it's off and it bugs me.

I've found some people that I think got it working with some xorg.conf tweaks using nvidia drivers, but I'm using intel HD 520 graphics and I was under the impression xorg.conf is becoming more and more of a legacy .conf file.